# How to get current date to last 6 quarter from date and to date in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is September month. I want the Current Quarter From date and To date and Previous 6 Quarters from date and To date?

Comment: what was your approach so far?

Comment: I want some count in between the date of every quarter.

Answer (score 0):

```
with Nums (NN) as
(
select level - 1
from dual
connect by level <=7
)

select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'Q'), -3*NN) as startdate,
       add_months(trunc(sysdate,'Q'), -3*NN +3)-1 as enddate
from Nums
```

Comment: it's possible in separate separate quarter?

Answer (score 0):

select sysdate-level from dual connect by level<=to_char(sysdate,'ddd')-to_char(add_months(sysdate,-6),'ddd');